# JQuery slider issue - slide every X seconds

Tags: jquery, html, slider

I am trying to get my slider to slide every 7 seconds. Is there any way of doing this by just modifying this code or adding a bit to it rather than rewriting it?

```
$('#buttons a').click(function(){
    var integer = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('#promotional-slide .cover').animate({left:-640*(parseInt(integer)-1)})  /*----- Width of div promo-section (here 160) ------ */
    $('#buttons a').each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
        if($(this).hasClass('button'+integer)){
            $(this).addClass('active')}
    });
}); 

$('.scroll-right').click(function(){
    $('#promotional-slide .cover').animate({left:-640})  

});

$('.scroll-left').click(function(){
    $('#promotional-slide .cover').animate({left:640})  

});

$('.regions ul li a').click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggle();
    return false;
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval(function(){
   $('#buttons a').trigger('click');
}, 7000)
```

Comment: This works, but only once - it only slides once after 7 seconds.. I also need it to reset and repeat after all slides have been shown

Comment: check out this http://jsfiddle.net/rfES8/ there seems to work as you need. I don't understand why is called just once for you..

Answer (score 0):

Work for me using Jquery Slider:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('.next').trigger('click');
}, 5000);
```